# how to show success message on keyclock page in django?

Tags: python, django, keycloak, keycloak-connect

```
{% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{message.tags}}" {% endif %}>
         <i class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill"></i>
            {{ message }}   
      </li> 
    {% endfor %}
            </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I want to show this message on keycloak page. it's server is different from our Django project
now how can show success message displaying on keyclock page

The view returns success and error message

```
response = requests.post(reset_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200 and response.json()["statuscode"] == "E_SUCC":
    messages.success(request,"You should receive an email with further instructions")
else:
    messages.error(request,"Email not found.")
```

Comment: how is this question related to keycloak-connect? Which Keycloak Page are you talking about, the Login Page?

Comment: Yes, the login keycloack page

Comment: Keycloak does not use Django. To customize the login page check out the docs at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes

Comment: yes we have customized keyclok but the Django server and keycloak servers are different so  how can I show the message on keycloak login page